# Parsing tab or space/s delimited file using Python

Tags: python

I have a file where each word is separated by either single space or tab or multiple spaces:

e.g.

address1.txt:

```
Bob lives in Boston
Sam lives    in Houston
Jay       lives in Ruston
Bill        lives in           Atlanta
```

I want to save the file as address2.txt where each word is tab separated.

How can i do it using Python?

Any help?

Thanks
Rio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `split` to split on whitespace, then `join` to put the words back together with tabs.

```
with open('address1.txt') as fin, open('address2.txt','w') as fout:
  for line in fin:
    fout.write( "\t".join(line.split()) + "\n" )
```

Comment: I also suggest using the `with` context manager for handling open files.

Comment: And one would not use `readlines()` of course. Iterating over the file with `for line in fin:` is the way to go.

Comment: Edited to incorporate your improvements.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do `'\t'.join(line.split())` on each line of the file. This works because `split()` with no arguments breaks up the line on any sequence of whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with open('address1.txt', 'r') as ro, \
    open('address2.txt', 'a') as rw:
      for line in ro.readlines():
          ls = line.strip().split()
          rw.write('\t'.join(ls) + '\n')
```

Comment: How is that substantively different from my answer?

Comment: with will make sure to close it.